# simple help in tic-tac-toe python

Tags: python

I'm creating a program that manages a Tic-tac-toe game, I'm creating a list of lists

```
[['', '', ''], 
 ['', '', ''], 
 ['', '', '']]
```

to create the game grid, I would like the program to stop when it finds a match like

```
[['x', 'x', 'x'],
 ['', '', ''],
 [ '', '', '']
```

In this case for example, I would therefore need to be able to say that in the other boxes there could be any character, 'o', 'x', ''

I would that python if the grid is a winning grid the program must stop

Comment: I don't know how to tell python that in the other case could be any symbol, the game must stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do to check "by hand" ?

1. check first row if all three positions are the code of the player

   `if b[0][0]==code and b[0][1]==code and b[0][2]==code: return True`
2. check second row
3. check third row
4. check first column if all three are the code of the player

   `if b[0][0]==code and b[1][0]==code and b[2][0]==code: return True`
5. check second and third column too
6. check first and second diagonal too

for the rows and cols is easy to write a loop instead of copy-paste the code

There are also other ways to write either shorter code (using things like `all(b[i][j] == code for j in range(3))`) or faster code (using things like bits instead of characters and a single integer for all `x`s or `o`s).

Another "trick" would be keeping the board in a single array instead of a matrix and using a placeholder (e.g. '-') for empty squares

```
board = ['-', '-', '-',
         '-', '-', '-',
         '-', '-', '-']
```

then you can check for winning strikes using a regular expression

```
s = "".join(board) # change to a single string
if re.match("xxx......", s) return True # first row check
if re.match("...xxx...", s) return True # second row check
if re.match("......xxx", s) return True # third row check
if re.match("x..x..x..", s) return True # first col check
if re.match(".x..x..x.", s) return True # second col check
if re.match("..x..x..x", s) return True # third col check
```

What I would do is using bits: the board is represented by two numbers 0...511: one number for where the `x` marks are and another for where the `o` marks are:

```
# board bits are
#
#     1      2      4
#     8     16     32
#    64    128    256
#
Xs = Os = 0 # empty board

win_codes = [1+2+4, 8+16+32, 64+128+256, # rows
             1+8+64, 2+16+128, 4+32+256, # cols
             1+16+256, 4+16+64]          # diags

def wins(pos):
    return any((pos & c) == c for c in win_codes)
```

given that the total number of positions is also small (512) the winning ones can also be precomputed and stored in a table

```
win_pos = [wins(pos) for pos in range(512)]
```

then the check is simply

```
if win_pos[Xs]: ...  # player X won the game
```

Comment: isn't possible to make a list that contain all possible winning grid, so a grid with all position in first raw are equal and the other position could be everything, maybe with the re.match module I can be able to say this?

Comment: @MISTERCEC: I've added a regexp based approach

Comment: oh perfect, so I can convert a list of list directly in a single list?

Comment: @MISTERCEC: for example with `"".join("".join(row) for row in board)`

Comment: oh you're method is lot clever can you explain me more of this?

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly interpreted what you are trying to say, you don't need to. Python is not statically-typed -- that is, any variable can hold any type. In a statically typed language, you would need to declare (or have it inferred for you) that your game grid is of type `list of list of char`, or equivalent. So, you can just set the element at any position to be whatever you want -- including characters like 'o' and 'x'.

**TL;DR** you don't need to.

*Note: it is generally considered bad style to change the type of a variable in the middle of a program for no reason, as this can confuse you and other people.*

Comment: no, sorry I must change the title you're right , I want that when the program arrive in a position like:                          [['x', 'x', 'x'],
 ['', 'o', ''],
 [ 'o', '', o''].   it stop because a player win, so when in a list I have this.       ['x', 'x', 'x'],  whatever the characters are present in the other lists the game must stop

Comment: @MISTERCEC, that doesn't seem to be the same question as what you wrote in your question? Your title 'how to tell python that any char is fine' implies that you want a way to show the interpreter that your jagged list can contain any character, and this, as I've said in my answer, is not necessary